# compile time evaluated list of string literals

Tags: c++, constexpr

i am searching for a way to register some constant string information to a class, and the class holds a list of them, and the list be available at the begining of the program, so i thought the way should be related to constexpr function and member function but i couldn't find a way, at the simplest way i want something like the below psudo-code:

holderclass.cpp

```
class Holder {
  string data_list[];
  void registerInfo(string info) {
     data_list.append(info);
  }
}
```

othercomponen.cpp

```
class Comp {
  Comp(){
    Holder::registerInfo("some information");
  }
  .....
}
```

i need the collected data at the **begining of the main function**.

so is there any way to achieve this goal with a class based solution? if there isn't, what other solutions can give different classes to add their info at compile time?

thank you.

Comment: Do you need it at compile time or "at the begining[sic] of the main function"? These aren't the same thing.

Comment: If you need the class content available **before** main, then make a global instance of your class.  If you need the content available *at the beginning* of `main`, then instantiate you class at the beginning of `main`, like as the first declaration.

Comment: `Holder::registerInfo(...);`  makes it look like a `static` or base class member function. However, it's neither.

Comment: Didn't know that `std::string[]` supports the `.append()` method.

Comment: @NicolBolas i want them to be available at the begining of the main.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews other classes are gonna register their info by the order they get initialize, so i do not think having a Holder instance at the main begining answer the question.

Comment: Instead of pseudo-code, can you show what you're _actually_ trying to do, and also, the full error message you get?

Comment: @TedLyngmo but i need them at the begining of the main, there are a few tasks and threads spawning at different time, so how should i achieve that?

Comment: @Joel its just a pseudo-code

Comment: @AhmadMansoori overread that, my bad

Comment: @AhmadMansoori Pseudo-code obscures what you are really trying to do. Can you show what you need to do with non-`constexpr` code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't need them to be `constexpr`, but rather just at the beginning of your `main()` function and probably access your `Holder` class from multiple files, I would suggest to use only `static` methods and members.

By default, all attributes of a `class` are private and `Comp` could not access them (if they are not friends). So I guess you want `registerInfo()` to be `public`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Holder {
    Holder() = delete;      // so you can't instanciate it
    static inline std::vector<std::string> dataList{};
public:
    static void registerInfo(const std::string& info) {
        dataList.push_back(info);
    }
};

class Comp {
public:
    Comp() {
        Holder::registerInfo("some information");
    }
};
```

Comment: int main()
    {
        for (auto &item : Holder::dataList)
        {
            std::cout << item << std::endl;
        }
        // Com instantiate here
        Comp c;
    }   ---- this is not going to do the job

Comment: @AhmadMansoori What do you mean by `Com instantiate here Comp c;`? Why not update your question with less pseudo-code and more real code that shows intent?

Comment: @AhmadMansoori I am sorry but I have no idea what your comment is supposed to mean. Do you want to access `Holder::dataList` from main? Then make it public. Do you want to print the `Holder::dataList` containing `Comp c;` before creating `Comp c;`? That won't work if its not created before or globally.